# Why are the contents inside <div> element not clickable?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a button inside of a div, but the content inside the div isn't clickable. My code:

```html
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="img/whitelogo.svg">
                    <img src="img.svg"></li>
            <li><img src="img.svg">
                    <a href="#">about me</a></li>
            <li><img src="img.svg">
                    <a href="#">submit</a></li>
            <li><img class="nav_icons" src="img.svg">
                    <a href="#">get in touch</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="about">
        <div>CLOSE DRAWER</div>
        <div>
            <img src="logo.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="submit">
        SUBMIT
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
        CONTACT
    </div>
```

Any idea?

Comment: You haven't posted any CSS or JS and there's nothing about your HTML that is obviously wrong (besides using `<div>` instead of `<button`>). Post a snippet that reproduces the issue.

Comment: where is the button ?

Comment: Because there is no button or link

Comment: How do I add them?

Comment: What is your end goal? You can attach a click handler on your existing elements too but your question is vague. @BorghiDaln

Comment: I want to make the `<div>` element a link

Comment: @BorghiDaln You can't use `<div>` for buttons or links.  Use `<a>` or `<button>` instead. The `<div>` element should only be used for non-semantic **block-level** divisions (and not for _inline_-layout text or widgets, use `<span>` for that)- but your HTML is using `<div>` everywhere, which is incorrect. You need to use semantic HTML (e.g. use `<h2>` for content headings, `<section>`, `<main>`, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you also provide your CSS code, please?
There aren't any clickable items in the `div` element.

```html
<div>
    <a>content...</a>
    <!-- <button>content</button>-->
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can't the `<div>` element handle links?

Comment: @BorghiDaln no, unless you use javascript

Comment: Or you can use `display: block;` (in CSS) to let the `<a>` element **looks like** a `<div>`.

Comment: Replaced `<div>` with `<a>` and achieved what I want, thx.

Comment: You can also put an `<a>` element **OUTSIDE** the `<div>` w/o CSS settings.

Answer (score 1):

There is no button or link in the element you mentioned.

```
     <div id="contact">
        CONTACT
    </div>
```

You can use it like below so you can click here..

```
    <div id="contact">
        <button id="foo">CONTACT</button>
    </div>
```